# How to make Chrome Dev Tools show the JavaScript source

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I slightly modified the `hello-world.cc` sample, importing some code from `d8`. Then, using [websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) and [asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/), I added a WebSocket Server to the program.
Also, I used [V8 inspector from an embedder standpoint](https://medium.com/@hyperandroid/v8-inspector-from-an-embedder-standpoint-7f9c0472e2b7) to add a simple implementation for the inspector protocol back-end.

Now, when I start my program and then use Chrome to navigate to `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9002`, I receive the following messages from the CDT:

```
{"id":1,"method":"Profiler.enable"}
```

for witch the response is:

```
{"id":1,"result":{}}
```

then

```
{"id":2,"method":"Runtime.enable"}
```

for this one a notification and a response are sent:

```
{"method":"Runtime.executionContextCreated",
 "params":{"context":{"id":1,"origin":"","name":"MyApplication"}}}

{"id":2,"result":{}}
```

then:

```
{"id":3,"method":"Debugger.enable"}
```

again, a notification and a response sent back to the front-end:

```
{"method":"Debugger.scriptParsed",
 "params":{
  "scriptId":"4","url":"func_add.js","startLine":0,
  "startColumn":0,"endLine":0,"endColumn":35,
  "executionContextId":1,"hash":"365568ee6245be1376631dbf20e7de9d42c9adf1",
  "isLiveEdit":false,"sourceMapURL":"","hasSourceURL":false,
  "isModule":false,"length":35
  }
}

{"id":3,"result":{"debuggerId":"(DC239109305DBEF825A955524584A826)"}}
```

For the moment, I will not add to the question the other messages received from the front-end, and the responses sent.
The last exchange is:

```
    {"id":7,"method":"Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger"}
    {"id":7,"result":{}}
```

My problem: in CDT, the `Sources` tab is empty (and therefore, I can't try to put a breakpoint).

My code to inject JS in V8:

```
const char * pszScript = "function add( a, b) { return a+b; }";
v8::Local<v8::String> source =
  v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, pszScript, v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
v8::Local<v8::String> name =
  v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "func_add.js", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
ExecuteString( isolate, source, name );
```

My `ExecuteString` function:

```
bool ExecuteString(v8::Isolate* isolate, v8::Local<v8::String> source,
                   v8::Local<v8::Value> name) {

  v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
  v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
  v8::TryCatch try_catch(isolate);
  try_catch.SetVerbose(true);

  v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> maybe_result;
  bool success = true;
  v8::ScriptOrigin origin(name);

  v8::ScriptCompiler::Source script_source(source, origin);
  v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Script> maybe_script;
  maybe_script = v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(context, &script_source);

  v8::Local<v8::Script> script;
  if (!maybe_script.ToLocal(&script)) {
    // Print errors that happened during compilation.
    ReportException(isolate, &try_catch);
    return false;
  }

  maybe_result = script->Run(context);

  v8::Local<v8::Value> result;
  if (!maybe_result.ToLocal(&result)) {

    // Print errors that happened during execution.
    ReportException(isolate, &try_catch);
    return false;
  }

  if (!result->IsUndefined()) {
    // If all went well and the result wasn't undefined then print
    // the returned value.
    v8::String::Utf8Value str(isolate, result);
    fwrite(*str, sizeof(**str), str.length(), stdout);
    printf("\n");
  } else {
    printf("undefined\n");
  }
  return success;

}
```

I think I am doing something wrong, as I should be able to see some `func_add.js` source in CDT with the content `function add( a, b) { return a+b; }`

Answer (score 1):

W/o checking the source code at all, I remember having some bad times at this exact use case.

try adding to your source parameter a protocol.
CDT needs any protocol file, http, https to create the sources tree.
It will also use this uri to request for maps, or any other source code related thing.

```
v8::Local<v8::String> name =
  v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "file://func_add.js", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
ExecuteString( isolate, source, name );
```

It also happens from time to time, that depending on your v8 implementation, official chrome is not able to show source code, debug, etc.
Try using chrome canary if this is the case.

The protocol implementation is as I described in your referenced post.
Hope this helps.

In your code, I don't see where you discover your Context to the Inspector object, but something like this must happen somewhere in your code:

```
inspector_->contextCreated(
            v8_inspector::V8ContextInfo(context, 1, v8_inspector::StringView(
                    reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>("ABCD"), 4)));
```

I do this right after creating the Context and setting its global object.

CDT will query script contents with a message of the form:

```
{"id":8,"method":"Debugger.getScriptSource","params":{"scriptId":"7"}}
```

While the implementation is very simple, there are many reasons why your code simply will not show up.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the `contextCreated` call was in my code; just copy/pasted from your code :-). Will try the "file://" hint and let you know. Btw, your "embedder standpoint" page is some kind of Internet miracle, thank you for that.

Comment: Some news: I used "CDT on CDT" to see the WebSocket traffic. My answers/notifications seems correct, with successful json parsing. Still no "Debugger.getScriptSource" request (with or without "file://" prefix")

Comment: You might have tried this before, but I went throughout: [inspector_test.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/test/inspector/inspector-test.cc?g=0) and scavenged most of the thing out just to have a pristine minimal example of what i wanted. The TaskRunner structure is a must. The methods quit/runMessageLoopOnPause will re-enter synchronously on the message loop (e.g. dev tools populates info on variables on top of the source code, etc.). This was the trickiest part.
On my side this works on an embedded android app beautifully. I might need to revisit the article and reflect this too.

Comment: I will do that when I will be able to see my JS source in CDT and be able to set a breakpoint... You will find here the WebSocket traffic: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/hWtRnVSiyb8/obDYEAxvCQAJ

Comment: Some progress. I was missing the third slash in my "file://" tests. Now the file is visible in CDT. Do you know what well formed "origin" I must use when compiling a scriptlet, with no real file?

Comment: ooh. nice !!!
There's actually no need for a valid one. Could be any. But bear in mind, CDT will use that source protocol to request extra info, e.g. maps. You should make your WS server be able to understand requests of e.g. blahblah.map.js, and thus serve the files it asks for.
Other than that, the protocol is transparent. It is just decoration on CDT tree file afaik. So sounds reasonable it to be http:// ?

Comment: in fact a full url is the convenient one, mostly where your WS server is waiting for some external connections. Stuff w/o any protocol prefix will appear under a `no domain` node. And all prefixed with a url, under a node with the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191734/discussion-between-hyperandroid-and-manuell).